# issues with R !duplicated and how to give precedence in a Dataframe

Tags: r

I have a rather unique issue which I cannot find a solution to. Every wednesday "headoffice" posts an updated CSV file of new data on their site which I download as a dataframe, BHAfile, and append to the main dataframe, OriginalData, and then remove duplicates because we often enter a few rows/records locally during the week to ensure accuracy of reports etc and keep 'realtime' ish. This works fine, however often some of the rows that have been entered locally during the week (between updates from headoffice) contains small errors  in a few of the minor 15 variables/columns - however, the 'Name' is alway 100% accurate in both dataframes which is why it is the 'key' for removing duplicates. Thus, I would like to give preference to the  updated BHAfile rather than the originalData when the !duplicated function is applied - the errors are minor and in a variety of cols, so the only way I can ensure 100% accuracy is to give preference to the newer data which I presume I could do by if I could give preference to higherlower row numbers (depending on the bind) in the 'binded' BHA file for duplciate removal, but I do not know how to do this. Thanks, in advance - a 'hair tearing out' problem that has bugged me for weeks.

```
BHAfile <- rbind (BHAfile,OriginalData)
BHAfile <- BHAfile[!duplicated(BHAfile[,c('Name')]),]
BHAfile <- BHAfile[order(BHAfile$Name),]
write.csv(BHAfile, file ="MasterHorseDb.csv",row.names = FALSE )
```

Comment: `duplicated` has a `fromLast` argument that should help you do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this by adding fromLast = TRUE to the !duplicated function but it has not worked todate. However, seeing that you have confirmed what I thought might be the solution I will work at in on that basis. Thanks for your time and pointing me in the right direction.